# how to exctract data from json file python

Tags: python, arrays, json, deep-learning

I have a json file with name data.json and here's the form of the included data:

```
{
"created_at": "Fri Oct 12 00:00:00 +0000 2012", "text": "ottimes daily top stories ghostlightning secretanimelov erojunko",
 "user": {"id": 163444845, "followers_count": 853},
 "retweet_count": 0,
 "entities": {"hashtags": [], "user_mentions": []}}
```

and i just want to extract value of the field "hashtags". so how can i do that please?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go if you have a json string:

```
json_string = '{ "created_at": "Fri Oct 12 00:00:00 +0000 2012", "text": "ottimes daily top stories ghostlightning secretanimelov erojunko", "user": {"id": 163444845, "followers_count": 853}, "retweet_count": 0, "entities": {"hashtags": [], "user_mentions": []}}'

data_dict = json.loads(json_string)

hashtags = data_dict['entities']['hashtags']
```

To open a json file run this first:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    json_string = file.read()
    data_dict = json.loads(json_string)
    hashtags = data_dict['entities']['hashtags']
```

Comment: but they are in a file?

Comment: I adjusted my answer

Answer (score 0):

Python has set of [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) functions that you can use.

To open a file, you can use [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function to open the file in read mode and consume the content like this

```py
import json

with open("./sample.json", 'r') as my_json_file:
    content = my_json_file.read()  # read content
    data = json.loads(content)     # parse content to a dictionary
    print(data['entities']['hashtags']) # access fields

my_json_file.close() # close file
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to enter a single key, the recursive function below will do it for you.

```py
def find_value_by_key(iterable, findkey):
    """recursive method to return the value for the first
    instance of 'findkey'."""
    if type(iterable) == list:
        for item in iterable:
            result = find_value_by_key(item, findkey)
            if result != None:
                return result
    elif type(iterable) == dict:
        for key in iterable:
            value = iterable[key]
            if key == findkey:
                return value
            elif type(value) == dict or type(value) == list:
                result = find_value_by_key(value, findkey)
                if result != None:
                    return result
    return None


jsondata = json.loads("""{
"created_at": "Fri Oct 12 00:00:00 +0000 2012", "text": "ottimes daily top stories ghostlightning secretanimelov erojunko",
 "user": {"id": 163444845, "followers_count": 853},
 "retweet_count": 0,
 "entities": {"hashtags": [], "user_mentions": []}}
 """)

print(find_value_by_key(jsondata, 'hashtags'))
```